# Como configurar a quantidade de números de expoente na notação científica em C++

Tags: c, c++, formatação, printf

Meu código esta dando o erro na apresentação do número cientifico, pois ele sempre aparece com 3 casas decimais sendo necessárias somente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float num=0.0;

    scanf("%f",&num);
    printf("%.4e",num);
    return 0;
}
```

Está saindo:

> 6.0221e+023

Entrada:

> 602214085774747474747474

O correto:

> 6.0221e+23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está tudo ok em compilador que funciona de acordo com a especificação.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float num;
    scanf("%f", &num);
    printf("%.4e\n", num);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Y54ZyZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qamlnekg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/SciNotationExpoent.c).

Se estiver usando um compilador que faz errado precisa ver como ele oferece uma solução, se oferece (senão, aí tem que aceitar assim mesmo). Se for o compilador da Microsoft tem que usar isto: [`_set_output_format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/set-output-format?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para configurar.

Comment: isso mesmo, estava usando no windows.Obrigado!